# Prevent OS X 10.11 to display "can't read disk" message

Tags: macos, filesystem, sd-card

I always have connected to my MBPr a Transcend JetDrive Lite 330.

[JetDrive Web](https://es.transcend-info.com/apple/jetdrivelite/)

I have installed Ubuntu on that SD Card, so it has EXT4 file system. I installed  some packages on the Mac for being able to mount that SD Card in case I need it. The packages are:

- [FUSE for OS X](https://osxfuse.github.io/)
- [fuse-ext2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/)

I'm completely able to mount the SD Card volume to a mountpoint which I created for this purpose:

```
sudo mount -t fuse-ext2 /dev/disk2s1 ~/.linux/
```

Now you know the antecedents.

Every time I turn on the Mac, the system shows this message.

[image: SD Card File System was not readable]

Is there any way to avoid this message? I don't want to auto mount the SD Card, I have created an alias for that. I need to avoid this message. It's very annoying.

diskutil list shows the following:

[image: sudo diskutil list]

/dev/disk2s1 is ubuntu

/dev/disk2s2 is, obviously, the swap

/dev/disk2s3 has no format. I didn't use it. I plan to install there some other things or use as more space. I didn't decided yet.

Comment: Hi klanomath, I download the .dmg from SourceForge and execute the .pkg . I install fuse-ext2 v0.0.7

Comment: In my opinion this is either related to the FileVault encryption of your main drive or one/two of the 3 partitions of the SD card is/are formatted with an other file system than ext4.

Comment: disk2s2 is a swap. disk2s3 hasn't be formatted yet. I think is the swap partition.

Comment: I finally delete the swap partition and format the disk (except linux partition) in exfat. All goes good now. Thanks klanomath